# How to Console Log all Hyperlinks href in a Box Using Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can you please let me know how to console log all `href` of `<a>` tags in a div `#res` using pure JavaScript. I have a div like

```
<div id="res">
<a href="ssssssss-1.html">Data</a>
<a href="ssssssss-2.html">Data</a>
<a href="ssssssss-3.html">Data</a>
<a href="ssssssss-4.html">Data</a>
<a href="ssssssss-5.html">Data</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('#res a');
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
  console.log(links[i].href);
};
```

```html
<div id="res">
<a href="ssssssss-1.html">Data</a>
<a href="ssssssss-2.html">Data</a>
<a href="ssssssss-3.html">Data</a>
<a href="ssssssss-4.html">Data</a>
<a href="ssssssss-5.html">Data</a>
</div>
```

Comment: that is nice, but and we got a pagination added and you whant all the hrefs from that page?

Comment: Change the query parameter in the querySelectorAll to accommodate your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `querySelectorAll()` to grab the required elements, iterate over it and print its `href` attribute by using `.getAttribute(attributeName)` function,

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#res > a")).forEach(function(itm){
  console.log(itm.getAttribute('href'));
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dnwdtgkn/)

Comment: Even do it looks cool, Array.from is new and not supported by Safari, IE (except Edge in Win10), mobile browsers (except Mozilla) ... if you still want it Mozilla has a nice Polyfill to help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: @RaduMaris It seems all browsers support `Array.from` now except IE (which is End of Life).